# Radio button selection when building HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form that is used for bookings. Once completed it submits the fields via e-mail which can then be automatically uploaded into my Access database with VBA.
The process works fine if there is just text in the form but I want to include radio button choices as well. The problem is that it doesn't include an indication as to which button has been chosen.
The body of the e-mail, if "text" was entered into the text box and choice2 was selected would be:
text
Choice1
Choice2
Choice3
What I would like it to be is:
text
Choice2.

Can this be done?
A simplified version of my code so far is:

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('Choice');

  for (j = 0; j < ele.length; j++) {
    if (ele[j].checked)
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ele[j].value;
  }
}

function btnClick() {
  var link = "mailto:username@domain.com" +
    "&subject=" + escape("Radio button trial") +
    "&body=" + escape(buildForm());

  window.location.href = link;
}

function buildForm() {
  var str = "";
  var elem = document.getElementById('RBT').elements;
  for (var i = 1; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].type != "button") {
      str += elem[i].value + "\r\n";
    }
  }

  return str;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="RBT" name="RBT">
    <fieldset>
      <p></p>
      <legend>Complete the form and\or choose an option</legend><br>
      <div>
        <label for "text1">Text1</label><br>
        <input id="text1" name="text1"><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="Choice" value="Choice1" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()">
        <label for="radio1">Choice1</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="Choice" value="Choice2" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
        <label for="radio2">Choice2</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="Choice" value="Choice3" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
        <label for="radio3">Choice3</label><br>
        <br></div>
      <div id="result" name="result" value="result"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <BUTTON type=submit onclick="btnClick()" />
  <FONT size=5 bold>Submit choice</FONT>
  </BUTTON>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the element is checked.
And since you're adding it in the same loop as the text field you also need to make sure the element that has to be checked is actually a radio button:

```
  if(elem[i].type != "radio" || elem[i].checked) {  
    str += elem[i].value + "\r\n";
  }
```

But: In your snippet everything is added to the `TO` field of the mail, is that intended?

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('Choice');

  for (j = 0; j < ele.length; j++) {
    if (ele[j].checked)
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ele[j].value;
  }
}

function btnClick() {
  var link = "mailto:username@domain.com" +
    "&subject=" + escape("Radio button trial") +
    "&body=" + escape(buildForm());

  window.location.href = link;
}

function buildForm() {
  var str = "";
  var elem = document.getElementById('RBT').elements;
  for (var i = 1; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].type != "button") {
      if(elem[i].type != "radio" || elem[i].checked) {  
        str += elem[i].value + "\r\n";
      }
    }
  }

  return str;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Radio button trial</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="RBT" name="RBT">
    <fieldset>
      <p></p>
      <legend>Complete the form and\or choose an option</legend><br>
      <div>
        <label for "text1">Text1</label><br>
        <input id="text1" name="text1"><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="Choice" value="Choice1" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()">
        <label for="radio1">Choice1</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="Choice" value="Choice2" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
        <label for="radio2">Choice2</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="Choice" value="Choice3" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
        <label for="radio3">Choice3</label><br>
        <br></div>
      <div id="result" name="result" value="result"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <BUTTON type=submit onclick="btnClick()" />
  <FONT size=5 bold>Submit choice</FONT>
  </BUTTON>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks iKiK. This is exactly what I wanted and intended and not to add all to the To field of the e-mail.

Comment: But it does. But that might just be my computer, if it works for you everything is fine, and if it doesn't that might be another problem anyways the return of the buildForm function should be correct now